# Не работает обработчик для динамической кнопки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Одно исправил, вот код:

```
// Клик "добавить"
    $(".btnProductCreate").click(function () {
        var rowTemplate = `
        <tr>
            <td style="display:none" class="product_id"></td>
            <td>
                <div class="view-row">
                    <div class="product_title"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="update-row">
                    <input type="text" class="btn-block form-control inputUpdateTitleProduct">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <div class="view-row">
                    <a class="btn btn-warning btnProductUpdate">Изменить</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger btnProductDelete">Удалить</a>
                </div>
                <div class="update-row" style="display:none">
                    <a class="btn btn-success btnProductSave">Сохранить</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger btnProductCancel">Отмена</a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        `;
        data = JSON.stringify({ Title: $("#inputProductTitle").val() });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: domen + "Product/Create",
            data: data,
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            processData: false,
            success: function (res) {
                var $row = $(rowTemplate);
                $row.find(".product_id").text(res.id);
                $row.find(".product_title").text(res.title);
                $("#productTbody").append($row);
            }
        });
    });
```

как видно из кода - добавляется кнопка с текстом `Изменить` и классом `btnProductUpdate`

Проблема в том что не работает обработчик ее

```
// Клик "изменить"
    $(".btnProductUpdate").on('click', function () {
        alert(123);
        let row = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
        row.find(".view-row").css("display", "none");
        row.find(".update-row").css("display", "block");
    });
```

По нажатию 123 не выводится (хотя я создаю в коде тестовую кнопку и она работает по аналогии)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делегирование обработки событий:

```
$("#productTbody").on('click', ".btnProductUpdate", function () {
  ...
```

Обработчик навешивается на существующий элемент с `id="productTbody"`.

Comment: спасибо еще раз))) знания по фронту мне явно надо подтянуть )))

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Пожалуйста. Успехов!